# OpenGL/Glut lighting doesn't make sense

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am having hard time figuring out my problem (if there is any problem) in lighting this blade. I don't understand why in those screenshots I have to move the light source to right to completely  lighten up the blade.

***Question:***

What I am asking is it would be great if you can run my code and test it by yourself and see if there is any error in lighting or I am simply wrong.

[*.exe file of program*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/58qurkpqmporpf0/Blade.exe?dl=0)

***Note:***

```
n ==> Toggles to show the Normal vectors
t ==> Twists the blade
f ==> Flattens the blade
up/down/right/left/+/- ==> Move the camera
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

static GLfloat lpos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0 };
static GLfloat white[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
static GLfloat black[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
static GLfloat red[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
static GLfloat yellow[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
static float alpha = 0.0;
static float beta = PI / 6.0;
static float zoom = 10.0;
static bool lightSource = true;
float twistConstant = 0;
float rotateConstant = 0;
float numberOfObj = 1;
float numberOfTriangles = 1;
static GLdouble cpos[3];
bool showNormalVectors = false;

float x;
float y;
float z;
float twistAng;
float twistCos;
float twistSin;
float yTwisted;
float zTwisted;


void DrawTopTriangleSet(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);


    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = -sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glNormal3f(x, sin(yTwisted), cos(zTwisted));
        glVertex3f(x, 0, y);
        glVertex3f(x, yTwisted, zTwisted);

    }
    glEnd();

}


void DrawTopTriangleSetNormalVector(){

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, white);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles-5){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = -sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glLineWidth(2.5);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(x, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(x, sin(yTwisted), cos(zTwisted));
        glEnd();

    }

}
void DrawBottomTriangleSet(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glNormal3f(x, sin(yTwisted), cos(zTwisted));
        glVertex3f(x, yTwisted, zTwisted);
        glVertex3f(x, 0, -y);
    }

    glEnd();
}

void DrawBottomTriangleSetNormalVector(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, white);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles-5){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glLineWidth(2.5);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(x, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(x, sin(yTwisted), cos(zTwisted));
        glEnd();
    }
}

void DrawBackTriangleSet(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = -sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glNormal3f(x, sin(yTwisted), -cos(zTwisted));

        glVertex3f(x, yTwisted, zTwisted);

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glNormal3f(x, sin(yTwisted), -cos(zTwisted));

        glVertex3f(x, yTwisted, zTwisted);
    }
    glEnd();

}


void DrawBackTriangleSetNormalVector(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, white);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles-5){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = -sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glLineWidth(2.5);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(x, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(x, sin(yTwisted), -cos(zTwisted));
        glEnd();

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glLineWidth(2.5);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(x, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(x, sin(yTwisted), -cos(zTwisted));
        glEnd();
    }

}

void DrawInsideTriangleSet(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = -sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;
        glVertex3f(x, yTwisted, zTwisted);

        glVertex3f(x, 0, y);

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glVertex3f(x, yTwisted, zTwisted);

    }

    glEnd();
}

void writemessage()
{
    printf(" X => x++ <= Move light source in direction of +X\n");
    printf(" Y => y++ <= Move light source in direction of +Y\n");
    printf(" Z => z++ <= Move light source in direction of +Z\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("^X => x-- <= Move light source in direction of -X\n");
    printf("^Y => y-- <= Move light source in direction of -Y\n");
    printf("^Z => z-- <= Move light source in direction of -Z\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" ^ => Move camera up\n");
    printf(" > => Move camera right\n");
    printf(" < => Move camera left\n");
    printf(" down arrow => Move camera down\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" t => More Twist\n");
    printf(" f => Less Twist\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" q => More Propeller\n");
    printf(" f => Less Propeller\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" w => More Triangles\n");
    printf(" s => Less Triangles\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" 0 => Toggling light source\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" r => Rotates Propeller\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" n => Toggle to show Normal Vectors\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" You can not move the light source when the light source is off !!!");
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 0.01, 20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    cpos[0] = zoom * cos(beta) * sin(alpha);
    cpos[1] = zoom * sin(beta);
    cpos[2] = zoom * cos(beta) * cos(alpha);
    gluLookAt(cpos[0], cpos[1], cpos[2], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    if (lightSource == true){
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lpos);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, white);
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(lpos[0], lpos[1], lpos[2]);
        glutSolidSphere(0.1, 10, 8);
        glPopMatrix();
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    }
    glRotatef(rotateConstant, 0, 0, 1);





    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObj; i++){
        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(i * 360 / numberOfObj, 0, 0, 1);

        DrawTopTriangleSet();
        DrawBottomTriangleSet();
        DrawBackTriangleSet();
        DrawInsideTriangleSet();

        if (showNormalVectors){
            DrawTopTriangleSetNormalVector();
            DrawBottomTriangleSetNormalVector();
            DrawBackTriangleSetNormalVector();
        }

        glPopMatrix();
    }


    // Cone
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(0, 0, -1.5);
    glutSolidCone(1, 2, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();

    // Back of Cone
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(cos(i*PI / 180) * 1, sin(i*PI / 180) * 1, -1.5);
    }

    glEnd();



    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}


void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case 27:
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 'x':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[0] = lpos[0] + 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'X':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[0] = lpos[0] - 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'y':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[1] = lpos[1] + 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'Y':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[1] = lpos[1] - 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'z':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[2] = lpos[2] + 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'Z':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[2] = lpos[2] - 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;

    case '+':
        if (zoom != 1.5)zoom = zoom - 0.5;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case '-':
        if (zoom != 15)zoom = zoom + 0.5;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case '0':
        if (lightSource == true){
            glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
            lightSource = false;
        }
        else{
            glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
            lightSource = true;
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 't':
        if (twistConstant <= PI / 4){
            twistConstant = twistConstant + 0.05;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
        break;
    case 'f':
        if (twistConstant >= 0){
            twistConstant = twistConstant - 0.05;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
        break;
    case 'r':
        rotateConstant = rotateConstant + 2;
        glutPostRedisplay();

        break;
    case 'q':
        if (numberOfObj <= 6){
            numberOfObj++;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }

        break;
    case 'a':
        if (numberOfObj >= 0){
            numberOfObj--;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }

        break;
    case 's':
        if (numberOfTriangles < 90){
            numberOfTriangles++;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }

        break;
    case 'w':
        if (numberOfTriangles > 1){
            numberOfTriangles--;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
    case 'n':
        if (showNormalVectors)
            showNormalVectors = false;
        else
            showNormalVectors = true;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}


void specialkey(GLint key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        alpha = alpha + PI / 180;
        if (alpha > 2 * PI) alpha = alpha - 2 * PI;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        alpha = alpha - PI / 180;
        if (alpha < 0) alpha = alpha + 2 * PI;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        if (beta < 0.45*PI) beta = beta + PI / 180;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        if (beta > -0.05*PI) beta = beta - PI / 180;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;


    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    writemessage();
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(1200, 800);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialkey);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

---

***Update:***

I changed the X value of all the normal vectors to 0 and apparently the problem is solved, apparently ...

For example:

```
    glNormal3f(x, sin(yTwisted), cos(zTwisted));
```

to

```
    glNormal3f(0, sin(yTwisted), cos(zTwisted));
```

[*updated .exe file of program*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/30rz3mwcj53ah8p/Blade-Updated.exe?dl=0)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: Do you really expect people to download an executable from a questionable source?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart final program has been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The program is finished.*

*I want to thank everyone who helped me finish this program.*

*Thanks again.*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

static GLfloat lpos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0 };
static GLfloat white[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
static GLfloat black[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
static GLfloat red[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
static GLfloat yellow[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
static float alpha = 0.0;
static float beta = PI / 6.0;
static float zoom = 10.0;
static bool lightSource = true;
float twistConstant = 0;
float rotateConstant = 0;
float numberOfObj = 3;
float numberOfTriangles = 1;
static GLdouble cpos[3];
bool showNormalVectors = false;
bool showInsideTriangleSet = true;

float x;
float y;
float z;
float twistAng;
float twistCos;
float twistSin;
float yTwisted;
float zTwisted;


void DrawTopTriangleSet(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);


    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = -sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glNormal3f(0, sin(yTwisted), cos(zTwisted));
        glVertex3f(x, 0, 2*y);
        glVertex3f(x, yTwisted, zTwisted);

    }
    glEnd();

}


void DrawTopTriangleSetNormalVector(){

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, white);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles - 5){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = -sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glLineWidth(2.5);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(x, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(x, sin(yTwisted), cos(zTwisted));
        glEnd();

    }

}
void DrawBottomTriangleSet(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glNormal3f(0, sin(yTwisted), cos(zTwisted));
        glVertex3f(x, yTwisted, zTwisted);
        glVertex3f(x, 0, -2*y);
    }

    glEnd();
}

void DrawBottomTriangleSetNormalVector(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, white);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles - 5){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glLineWidth(2.5);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(x, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(x, sin(yTwisted), cos(zTwisted));
        glEnd();
    }
}

void DrawBackTriangleSet(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = -sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glNormal3f(0, sin(yTwisted), -cos(zTwisted));

        glVertex3f(x, yTwisted, zTwisted);

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glNormal3f(0, sin(yTwisted), -cos(zTwisted));

        glVertex3f(x, yTwisted, zTwisted);
    }
    glEnd();

}


void DrawBackTriangleSetNormalVector(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, white);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles - 5){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = -sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glLineWidth(2.5);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(x, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(x, sin(yTwisted), -cos(zTwisted));
        glEnd();

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glLineWidth(2.5);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(x, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(x, sin(yTwisted), -cos(zTwisted));
        glEnd();
    }

}

void DrawInsideTriangleSet(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles){

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = -sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;
        glVertex3f(x, yTwisted, zTwisted);

        glVertex3f(x, 0, y);

        x = i*PI / 180;
        y = -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180);
        z = sin(i*PI / 180);
        twistAng = twistConstant * x;
        twistCos = cos(twistAng);
        twistSin = sin(twistAng);
        yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
        zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;

        glVertex3f(x, yTwisted, zTwisted);

    }

    glEnd();
}

void writemessage()
{
    printf(" X => x++ <= Move light source in direction of +X\n");
    printf(" Y => y++ <= Move light source in direction of +Y\n");
    printf(" Z => z++ <= Move light source in direction of +Z\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("^X => x-- <= Move light source in direction of -X\n");
    printf("^Y => y-- <= Move light source in direction of -Y\n");
    printf("^Z => z-- <= Move light source in direction of -Z\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" ^ => Move camera up\n");
    printf(" > => Move camera right\n");
    printf(" < => Move camera left\n");
    printf(" down arrow => Move camera down\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" t => More Twist\n");
    printf(" f => Less Twist\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" q => More Propeller\n");
    printf(" f => Less Propeller\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" e => More Triangles\n");
    printf(" d => Less Triangles\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" 0 => Toggling light source\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" r => Rotates Propeller\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" n => Toggle to show Normal Vectors\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" s => Toggle to show Inside Triangles\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" w => Toggle to show wire frame mode\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" You can not move the light source when the light source is off !!!");
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 0.01, 20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 64);
    cpos[0] = zoom * cos(beta) * sin(alpha);
    cpos[1] = zoom * sin(beta);
    cpos[2] = zoom * cos(beta) * cos(alpha);
    gluLookAt(cpos[0], cpos[1], cpos[2], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    if (lightSource == true){
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lpos);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, white);
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(lpos[0], lpos[1], lpos[2]);
        glutSolidSphere(0.1, 10, 8);
        glPopMatrix();
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    }
    glRotatef(rotateConstant, 0, 0, 1);





    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObj; i++){
        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(i * 360 / numberOfObj, 0, 0, 1);

        DrawTopTriangleSet();
        DrawBottomTriangleSet();
        DrawBackTriangleSet();

        if (showNormalVectors){
            DrawTopTriangleSetNormalVector();
            DrawBottomTriangleSetNormalVector();
            DrawBackTriangleSetNormalVector();
        }

        if (showInsideTriangleSet)
            DrawInsideTriangleSet();

        glPopMatrix();
    }


    // Cone
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(0, 0, -1.5);
    glutSolidCone(1, 2, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();

    // Back of Cone
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(cos(i*PI / 180) * 1, sin(i*PI / 180) * 1, -1.5);
    }

    glEnd();



    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}


void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    static int polygonmode[2];

    switch (key) {
    case 27:
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 'x':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[0] = lpos[0] + 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'X':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[0] = lpos[0] - 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'y':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[1] = lpos[1] + 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'Y':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[1] = lpos[1] - 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'z':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[2] = lpos[2] + 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'Z':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[2] = lpos[2] - 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;

    case '+':
        if (zoom != 1.5)zoom = zoom - 0.5;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case '-':
        if (zoom != 15)zoom = zoom + 0.5;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case '0':
        if (lightSource == true){
            glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
            lightSource = false;
        }
        else{
            glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
            lightSource = true;
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 't':
        if (twistConstant <= PI / 4){
            twistConstant = twistConstant + 0.05;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
        break;
    case 'f':
        if (twistConstant > 0){
            twistConstant = twistConstant - 0.05;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
        break;
    case 'r':
        rotateConstant = rotateConstant + 3;
        glutPostRedisplay();

        break;
    case 'q':
        if (numberOfObj <= 6){
            numberOfObj++;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }

        break;
    case 'a':
        if (numberOfObj >= 0){
            numberOfObj--;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }

        break;
    case 'd':
        if (numberOfTriangles < 90){
            numberOfTriangles++;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }

        break;
    case 'e':
        if (numberOfTriangles > 1){
            numberOfTriangles--;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
        break;
    case 'n':
        if (showNormalVectors)
            showNormalVectors = false;
        else
            showNormalVectors = true;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;

    case 'w': 
        glGetIntegerv(GL_POLYGON_MODE, polygonmode);
        if (polygonmode[0] == GL_FILL)
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        else glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 's':
        if (showInsideTriangleSet)
            showInsideTriangleSet = false;
        else
            showInsideTriangleSet = true;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}


void specialkey(GLint key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        alpha = alpha + PI / 180;
        if (alpha > 2 * PI) alpha = alpha - 2 * PI;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        alpha = alpha - PI / 180;
        if (alpha < 0) alpha = alpha + 2 * PI;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        if (beta < 0.45*PI) beta = beta + PI / 180;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        if (beta > -0.05*PI) beta = beta - PI / 180;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;


    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    writemessage();
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(1200, 800);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    /* initially GL_FILL mode (default), later GL_LINE to show wireframe */
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialkey);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```